# Get the numbers which resulted on another?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers

Here, in Brazil, some public exams use this alternatives system:

```
01 - Alternative bla
02 - Alternative omg
04 - Alternative god
08 - Alternative hey

TOTAL: [___]
```

This way, the students must `add` the values from the alternatives they want to mark, and tip in the `total number`. The values of the alternatives are defined by `2^(alternative_number - 1)`. So, the value of alternative 1 is 1, the value of alternative 2 is 2, the value of alternative 3 is 4, etc.

So, how can I get the values which `builded` the total number?

For example, I have `23`. This number was builded by adding `16 + 04 + 02 + 01`.

Comment: Look into converting the number into binary. The positions of the 1's will give you the index of the 'alternatives'.
e.g. 23 = 10111 (binary). This means that , from right to left, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 5th alternatives were used to build 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interpret the possible alternatives as bit masks and use `&`, the bit-wise `and` operator with the "total" value to test if one alternative was chosen:

```
if ((total &  1) != 0)
    System.out.println("Alternative 01 was selected");
if ((total &  2) != 0)
    System.out.println("Alternative 02 was selected");
if ((total &  4) != 0)
    System.out.println("Alternative 04 was selected");
if ((total &  8) != 0)
    System.out.println("Alternative 08 was selected");
if ((total & 16) != 0)
    System.out.println("Alternative 16 was selected");
```

The above code will tell you that `1`, `2`, `4` and `16` were selected. To visualize what's happening, let's convert the total value into binary representation, so `23` becomes:

```
  10111 // 23
```

And let's apply each of the bit masks in turn:

```
  10111 // 23
& 00001 //  1
-------
  00001 //  1 was selected
```

The above tells us that in fact the `1` option was selected. Similarly for the others:

```
  10111 // 23
& 00010 //  2
-------
  00010 //  2 was selected

  10111 // 23
& 00100 //  4
-------
  00100 //  4 was selected

  10111 // 23
& 01000 //  8
-------
  00000 //  8 was NOT selected

  10111 // 23
& 10000 // 16
-------
  10000 // 16 was selected
```

Comment: @BloodShura no problem, it was my pleasure :)